# SSRS - Parameter to include/exclude certain records

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We have a dataset that includes a field called "cancelled" that is a boolean field. I want the report to have a parameter called @includecancelled as boolean. The user could mark it as True or False to control whether to include cancelled records in the report. So far I haven't been able to find a way to do that. This is the basic outline of what I currently have:

```
SELECT TOP 10 COUNT (table1.field1) as Count_field1
  ,table2.fielda
  ,table2.fieldb
FROM
  table1
  INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.field1 = table2.fieldc
WHERE
  table1.field2 in (@param1)
GROUP BY
  table2.fielda
  ,table2.fieldb
ORDER BY COUNT (table1.field1) DESC
```

I'd like to have another statement in the WHERE clause to exclude or include records based on the "cancelled" field and the parameter the user chooses. So, something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 COUNT (table1.field1) as Count_field1
  ,table2.fielda
  ,table2.fieldb
FROM
  table1
  INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.field1 = table2.fieldc
WHERE
  table1.field2 in (@param1)
  IF (@includecancelled = TRUE, '', ',AND table1.cancelled = FALSE')
GROUP BY
  table2.fielda
  ,table2.fieldb
ORDER BY COUNT (table1.field1) DESC
```

Which obviously doesn't work, but is the general idea of what I'm wanting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a CASE statement.
**UPDATED**

```
SELECT TOP 10 COUNT (table1.field1) as Count_field1
  ,table2.fielda
  ,table2.fieldb
FROM
  table1
  INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.field1 = table2.fieldc
WHERE
  table1.field2 in (@param1)
  AND table1.cancelled = CASE WHEN @includecancelled = 1 THEN table1.cancelled ELSE 'FALSE' END
GROUP BY
  table2.fielda
  ,table2.fieldb
ORDER BY COUNT (table1.field1) DESC
```

Comment: That's almost there, but one issue. When they mark "includecancelled" as true, I want to return ALL values (not just the cancelled values). The FALSE part of your CASE is spot on. But the TRUE part only returns the cancelled values.

Comment: Updated above. Instead of 'TRUE', set table1.cancelled to itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 10 COUNT (table1.field1) as Count_field1
   ,table2.fielda
  ,table2.fieldb
FROM table1
  INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.field1 = table2.fieldc
WHERE
  table1.field2 in (@param1)
  and ((  @includecancelled = TRUE  ) 
  OR  ( @includecancelled = FALSE AND table1.cancelled = FALSE ))
GROUP BY table2.fielda,table2.fieldb
ORDER BY COUNT (table1.field1) DESC
```